# What's the difference between MySQL BOOL and BOOLEAN column data types?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I'm using MySQL version 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1. It allows me to define columns of two different data types: `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN`. What are the differences between the two types?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

They are both synonyms for **TINYINT(1)**.

Comment: What Adam says. There is no actual BOOLEAN type in MySQL.

Answer (score 26):

As established in other comments, they're synonyms for TINYINT(1).

**So, why do they bother differentiating between bool, boolean, tiny**int(1)?

Mostly semantics.

Bool and Boolean: MySQL default converts these to the tinyint type. Per a MySQL statement made around the time of this writing, "We intend to implement full boolean type handling, in accordance with standard SQL, in a future MySQL release."

0 = FALSE
1 = TRUE

TINYINT: Occupies one byte; ranges from -128 to +127; or, 0 – 256.

---

Commonly brought up in this comparison:
After MySQL 5.0.3 -- Bit: Uses 8 bytes and stores only binary data.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. What's the difference between `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN`?

Comment: Earlier posts had already established that both are synonymous with TINYINT(1). Ideally, the next question would be "Why, then, did they differentiate between the data types?"

Comment: @Sixthfore the `Bit: Uses 8 bytes and stores only binary data.` is incorrect information. When you add a bit column to your table it will occupy a whole byte in each record, not just a single bit. When you add a second bit column it will be stored in the same byte. The ninth bit column will require a second byte of storage.

Comment: @Kolyunya 

I'm interested in the bit storage implementation, could you please provide any reference doc or source code fragment that can prove the statement:

`When you add a bit column to your table it will occupy a whole byte in each record, not just a single bit. When you add a second bit column it will be stored in the same byte. The ninth bit column will require a second byte of storage.`

I'm trying to understand the mysql internal implementation.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I just noticed - with a column defined as BOOL in MySql, Spring Roo correctly generates Java code to unmarshall the value to a Boolean, so presumably specifying BOOL can add some value, even if it's only in the nature of a hint about the intended use of the column.

Answer (score 2):

check the MySQL docs overview of numeric types:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html