# Difference between BOOL and BOOLEAN types in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

What is the difference between `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` data types in MySQL?
Can `BIT` or `TINYINT` represent Booleans?

Comment: Google, while not used very often, is a pretty nifty tool I just learned out about...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753963/whats-the-difference-between-mysql-bool-and-boolean-column-data-types.  First hit at the top of the page.

Comment: Top google result for me: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/other-vendor-data-types.html

Answer (score 5):

`BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` are both *synonyms* of `TINYINT(1)`. So there is no difference.

[MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html)

Comment: `INT` and `INTEGER`, same idea.